# Missing "edu.cmu.sphinx.api" in my Sphinx 4 library

Tags: java, api, cmusphinx

Please, `sphinx4-1.0beta6` version of sphinx does not have `edu.cmu.sphinx.api` which contains essential classes like `Configuration` and `SpeechResult` needed for my speech recognition (live voice transcription) project.

So the question is this, how do I get the `edu.cmu.sphinx.api` that I saw in [Sphinx 4 Transcriber Demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java) and I can only work with Java and I am limited to Sphinx 4 which is implemented in Java.

I will appreciate if anyone can tell me the exact Sphinx 4 version that has the `edu.cmu.sphinx.api` in question.

Answer (score 0):

High level api is available in sphinx4-5prealpha

See for details

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4